# how can find header controls in gridview?

Tags: asp.net

In a web application, how can I find the controls in header, and how can I bind the value dynamically to those controls? This is what my gridview looks like...

```
    ----------------------------------------------
           |     October        |     November    |
    product|                    |                 |
           | self   |  Officer  | self   | officer|
    ----------------------------------------------
```

This is my gridview header. All are labels, now I want to find the label (october, noverber, self, officer..) how can I bind the data to them dynamically?

I have following code in gridview rowdatabound event.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdProducts.Rows)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        Label lM = (Label)gr.FindControl("lblMon1");
        lM.Text = month1 + "-" + year1;
        lM = (Label)gr.FindControl("lblMon2");
        lM.Text = month2 + "-" + year2;
        lM = (Label)gr.FindControl("lblMon3");
        lM.Text = month3 + "-" + year3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example.... @Surya sasidhar

In Aspx page.. I added below gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="grvGrid_RowDataBound">  
            <Columns>  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True"   
                    SortExpression="CustomerID" />  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName"   
                    SortExpression="CompanyName" />  
               <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMon1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblblbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>
```

At code behind page, I added below code.....

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetTable();
        grvGrid.DataSource = dstable;
        grvGrid.DataBind();
    }



protected void grvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            Label lblnothing = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblMon1");
            lblnothing.Text = "November";
        }

    }

private void GetTable()
    {
        dstable.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(int));
        dstable.Columns.Add("CompanyName", typeof(string));
        //
        // Here we add five DataRows.
        //
        dstable.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin");
        dstable.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel");
        dstable.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine");
        dstable.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent");
        dstable.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin");
    }
```

Here is the result....

[image]

Comment: Hello, Do you get your problem...?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it with below code snippet....

```
protected void gridview__RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
             Label lblOctober = (Label)GridView1.FindControl("NameOflabelOctober");
             lblOctober.Text = "What Ever you want to give value here(Same thing you can do for rest of four control.... ".

        }
     }
```

Comment: Sorry Mr.Sikender when i put break point the cursor is not entering in if condition

Comment: Remove if condition and then check it again.

Comment: I will try it, in my environment